How to utilize client certificates now that cURL has removed support for NSS
We recently upgraded from RHEL7 to RHEL8 and one of this issues that wasn't straight forward to handle is how to utilize cURL with client certificates after cURL removed support for NSS?
Previously, cURL just worked assuming we had imported client certificates into Firefox or Chrome already which utilize nssdb. cURL had nssdb available to and could choose a certificate stored in the DB.
Upon upgrading to RHEL8, we ultimately found this is no longer an option. Running curl -vv ... showed output like Initializing NSS with certpath: ... and NSS: using client certificate: ... on RHEL7, but no mention of NSS on RHEL8.
In research, I found mail traffic and pull request indicating its demise in August 2023.
Now that this support is gone, what are some alternatives to accessing URLs that are PKI protected with the no longer available cURL NSS pairing, whether it be from scripts or command line?
I've previously looked at python requests, but that doesn't allow for a password to a P12 file to be passed, which leaves one to explode the P12 into an unencrypted key/cert if it's to be automated.
UPDATE:
I found this article talking about how to do it with Windows, cURL client certificate with SCHANNEL. It sounds like SCHANNEL for Windows is similar to NSS for how cURL could automatically utilize a certificate in the NSS DB. Though this post also seems to indicate that it isn't working for Windows 11 either.
Is it possible to get cURL to pull a client certificate from some Linux system store?
Thanks everyone!

can't you use the --cert  --key  --cacert  options ? i use these options (at least the first two) when i want to test something and it requires mutual authentication and I need to send my certificate (along with the private key)

@olivierg That is possible, but gets complicated with an encrypted key, especially from a batch job perspective. The cURL version provided in RHEL7, just knew it could look in the user's nssdb for a previously loaded cert. We didn't have to code the cURL command to tell it how to do this. Now we have to mandate users setup their certificates in a different way, potentially compromising security if we also need the password, but also automated.

i see, thank you for the feedback
